# How do define custom displayNameGetter in PowerBI?

Tags: visualization, powerbi

I'm developing a new visual in PowerBI and first defining visual capabilities.
Even, the samples show me that, for example, gauge.capabilities.ts file like this.

```
    export var gaugeCapabilities: VisualCapabilities = {
    dataRoles: [
        {
            name: gaugeRoleNames.y,
            kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
            displayName: data.createDisplayNameGetter('Role_DisplayName_Value'),
        }, {
            name: gaugeRoleNames.minValue,
            kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
            displayName: data.createDisplayNameGetter('Role_DisplayName_MinValue'),
        }, {
            name: gaugeRoleNames.maxValue,
            kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
            displayName: data.createDisplayNameGetter('Role_DisplayName_MaxValue'),
        }, {
            name: gaugeRoleNames.targetValue,
            kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
            displayName: data.createDisplayNameGetter('Role_DisplayName_TargetValue'),
        }
    ],
```

I want to define custom display names like "From", "To". And when I trying to input it as "raw" in the dataRoles like:

```
dataRoles: [
        {
            name: gaugeRoleNames.y,
            kind: VisualDataRoleKind.Measure,
            displayName: 'From',
        }, { ...
```

And it works.
But I think this is out of coding requirements. Is there any way to define custom display name getter like:

```
displayName: data.createDisplayNameGetter('Role_DisplayName_From')
```

I tried. But it doesn't work.

**Does anyone have same issue and solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a function for displayName allows a visual to fetch a localized string.

The `data.createDisplayNameGetter` function returns a lambda that does a resource string lookup in our `PowerBI.resx` resources.

The custom visuals don’t currently have a way to do extend our `PowerBI.resx`.  So you can either hard-code (as you’ve done), or you can define your own function that does your own resource lookup.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Sachin.